# Add negative condition in InfluxDB: AND NOT (meter_id='500' AND conso_prod='Prod')

Tags: nosql, influxdb

I have this query in Influx 1.7

```
SELECT sum(delta) from measures  
WHERE operation_id='A1' 
AND time>'2020-05-19T22:00:00.000Z' AND time<'2020-05-26T22:00:00.000Z'  GROUP BY time(1d)
```

I want to exclude the results when  `(meter_id='500' AND conso_prod='Prod')`

So, I tried to add:

```
AND NOT (meter_id='500' AND conso_prod='Prod')
```

but it seems `NOT` is not supported by influx.

So, I tried to write the negative, but it seems `XOR` doesn't exists neither.

It seems easy, but I can't do it. Any idea how should I do ?

Comment: Did you try `AND  (meter_id!='500' OR conso_prod!='Prod')` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it doesn't exclude the 500 / Prod case. it is not an exclusive OR :(

Comment: add this to the `Where` clause: `AND ( (meter_id='500' AND conso_prod!='Prod') OR (meter_id!='500' AND conso_prod='Prod') )`

Comment: Yep, this one works. You can put it as answer Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your *Where* clause as follow:

```
SELECT sum(delta) from measures  
WHERE operation_id='A1' 
AND time>'2020-05-19T22:00:00.000Z' AND time<'2020-05-26T22:00:00.000Z'  

AND ( (meter_id='500' AND conso_prod!='Prod') OR (meter_id!='500' AND conso_prod='Prod') )

GROUP BY time(1d)
```